# Import xml to java

Tags: java, android, xml, dynamic, build

when a button is pressed i want to create some elements, like a TextView and a CheckBox. I now it's possible to do this in my java code, but... Is it possible to have a xml file with only those elements inside and call it when the button is pressed?

something like this:

java:

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //create whats in myxml

        }
```

and thats what i want to create (myxml.xml):

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/checkboxlayout"
    android:layout_marginTop="25px">

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".7"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".3"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/datelayout"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

hope someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to use the `<include` tag to include the *component layout* to the layout of your `Activity`/`Fragment`. The content of the component layout is retrievable with `findViewById`. Alternatively you could a [LayoutInflater](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to *convert* your xml, in `View`.

E.g.

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.name_of_layout, null);
```

where `name_of_layout.xml`, contains the component you want to transform. Be aware that the `inflater` returns a completely new `View` and it has to be added to the View's hierarchy of your `Activity`/`Fragment` if you want to deal with it

Comment: <include is what i was looking for. Thanks! I am new in java, so can you quickly tell me how i can use the <include layout="@layout/..." /> in the .java?

Comment: it's completely transparent. You just need to call `findViewById`